# What methods can be used for the numerical integration of an equation involving the rotation of the Earth?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, orbital-motion, angular-velocity, satellites

I've got an expression which involves the usual Newtonian gravitational potential $\phi$ for a near-Earth object orbiting the Earth with position $r^j$. This potential is expanded up to and including the usual zonal spherical  harmonic of degree two or, in other words

$$ \phi = \frac{GM}{r} + O(J_2), $$

I've also got a vector potential which can be cast in the following form

$$ \Phi^i = \phi v^i, $$

where $v^i = \epsilon_{ijk}\Omega^jr^k$ and the $\epsilon$ is the usual fully antisymmetric Levi Civita symbol and here denotes a vector cross product. Now, the expression $\Omega^j$ is the angular velocity of a matter distribution which in this case is the Earth. I am interested in performing some numerical methods. However, I do not necessarily want to use the $\Omega^j$. Does anyone know of any methods to recast the expression $v^i$ in simpler form. For example in terms of the moment of inertia tensor (I think I have seen this done somewhere before.. I am not 100% though). An suggestions?

Comment: You can't evaluate velocity in terms of moment of inertia without the angular velocity also being involved (that would be like trying to write $mv$ in terms of just $m$). And I'm not sure what could be simpler than the expression you already have; why would you not want to use $\Omega$?

Comment: @lemon point taken. I might need to add clarity as I am aware of the form of the moment of inertia tensor. I just meant in terms of numerical methods using the $Omega$ might over complicate things? Do you agree?

Comment: I'm still unclear about what you're actually trying to do: do you wish to solve $\Phi$ numerically over some spatial domain $r$? If $r$ is the position of a satellite then why is $\Omega$ the angular velocity of the Earth rather than the satellite? (And if it's a geostationary orbit then it surely wouldn't make sense to solve this over an expanse of space...)

Comment: @lemon I should be more clear: I've got an equation of motion which involves the above terms, or derivatives of them. I'm interested in applying some integration schemes to the motion of a satellite in the vicinity of the Earth that is rotating in the geocentric frame.